# Log authentication failures in Quarkus

Tags: security, authentication, quarkus

I have a REST application in which all methods require authentication. If a user calls a method without authentication information or he has not the required role, Quarkus sends http status 401/403 but does not log anything.

To analyze these calls, I want to log them in a specific format (SIEM), so I can automatically process the logs.

Is there a way to intercept failed authentication attempts?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if Quarkus would fire events for failed authentication attempts, so that we could easily observe them and do our own stuff with it.

I think at the moment you need to write a routefilter and check the response status code and log it.